# Eclipse dont start:EXIT CODE 13

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

Eclipse does not start: error EXIT CODE 13.

I use windows 10 64 bits.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit Eclipse requires a 64-bit JVM, and 32-bit Eclipse requires 32-bit JVM--you can not mix-and-match between 32-bit and 64-bit.
This is the most frequent cause of an Error 13